# How do I change position offset of wheelnav.js spreader title text

Tags: wheelnav.js

I have failed after several attempts, and massive search attempts (which I may have just failed at), to determine how to move the text in the spreader title to accommodate use of the spreaderStartAngle and spreaderSliceAngle settings, which allow for changing the wheel to smaller sizes (180 or 90 degree versions in my case).

The demo on the site shows the text moving away from the center (starting as a 360 degree circle) down to a quadrant. But in my own use, the re-positioning does not occur automatically, and I see no additional attributes being applied that would cause this.

I have dived into more detail and found that there is apparently something in the Rafael library that may being modified (when looking at the source on the demo page), but it is beyond my understanding on how to approach this via the existing methods.

Anything I have tried makes no change to the text location, which is always centered in what would have been a full circle, regardless of the actual spreader's start and end.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include examples of what you've tried already and refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for reporting this! I've modified the demo on the site, based on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position spreader's title via the [spreaderPathCustom](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/js/dist/wheelnav.js#L123) property.

```
wheel.spreaderPathCustom = spreaderPath().PieSpreaderCustomization();
wheel.spreaderPathCustom.titleRadiusPercent = 0.58;
wheel.spreaderPathCustom.titleSliceAnglePercent = 0.45;
```

[PieSpreaderCustomization](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/js/dist/wheelnav.js#L3308) belongs to PieSpreader. The above values of [titleRadiusPercent](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/js/dist/wheelnav.js#L2037) and [titleSliceAnglePercent](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/blob/v1.7.1/js/dist/wheelnav.js#L2038) are suitable for 90 degree.

Comment: Perfect. That's just what I needed. Your wheelnav tool is very comprehensive.